# How to copy rows from one workbook to another based on text in a specific column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all data in my template into four other workbooks based on the text in column "G".
I want it below any existing data in the target file.
All four workbooks would be open when this is running.

I get a compile error

> "method or data member not found"

in `For Each c In Source.Range("G1:G" & Source**.Cells**(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`

```vb
Sub CopyPastedata()
'copy and paste data from template into existing workbooks

Dim c As Range
Dim Source As Workbooks
Dim Target As Workbooks
Dim Target1 As Workbooks
Dim Target2 As Workbooks

'define source and targets for workbooks and worksheets
Set Source = Workbooks("CostIncreaseTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = Workbooks("Fresh.xlsx").Worksheets("Fresh")
Set Target1 = Workbooks("CannedGoods.xlsx").Worksheets("CannedGoods")
Set Target2 = Workbooks("Baking.xlsx").Worksheets("Baking")

'Specify where to search and copy the entire row if criteria is met and paste in target file in the next blank cell

For Each c In Source.Range("G1:G" & Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If c = "Fresh" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy
        Target.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ElseIf c = "CannedGoods" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy
        Target1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ElseIf c = "Baking" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy
        Target2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Source As Workbook` etc not as `Workbooks`

Comment: I think your dim should be `as worksheet`, because you include the sheet name in your `set = `

Answer (score 0):

### Export Rows

- The error occurs because you have declared `Source` as a workbooks collection object which has no `.Range` and no `.Cells` *method or data member*.

```vb
Sub ExportRows()

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Set Source = Workbooks("CostIncreaseTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' If the code is in 'CostIncreaseTemplate.xlsm', replace the previous line
    ' with:
    'Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = Source.Range("G2", Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = Source.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Target1 As Worksheet
    Dim Target2 As Worksheet
    
    Set Target = Workbooks("Fresh.xlsx").Worksheets("Fresh")
    Set Target1 = Workbooks("CannedGoods.xlsx").Worksheets("CannedGoods")
    Set Target2 = Workbooks("Baking.xlsx").Worksheets("Baking")
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim tCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), "Fresh", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set tCell = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), "CannedGoods", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set tCell = Target1.Cells(Target1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), "Baking", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set tCell = Target2.Cells(Target2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        End If
        If Not tCell Is Nothing Then
            ' When copying values only, copying by assignment is most efficient:
            tCell.Offset(1).Resize(, scCount).Value = sCell.EntireRow.Value
            Set tCell = Nothing
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Rows exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What would need to be changed to copy and paste the data with formulas or formatting?

Comment: Without looking too deep into it, possibly replace the copy-line with `sCell.EntireRow.Copy tCell.Offset(1)`.

Comment: It works! Thank you again for saving my bacon. :D